# How to check for a single character and break a loop

Tags: java

I have this loop:

```
String cont = "";
while ( cont != "n" ) {
// Loop stuff

System.out.print("another item (y/n)?");
cont = input.next();
}
```

However, when I type "n" to stop the loop, it just keeps running. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You're comparing objects instead of primitives. A `String` is an object, the `==` and `!=` doesn't compare objects by "internal value", but by reference.

You have 2 options:

1. Use [`Object#equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

   ```
   while (!cont.equals("n")) {
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Use the primitive `char` instead of `String`.

   ```
   char cont = 'y';
   while (cont != 'n') {
       // ...
       cont = input.next().charAt(0);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `equals()`:

```
while (!cont.equals("n")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ( !cont.equals( "n" ) ) {
```

Comment: @jschoen How is this a comment?

Comment: @ColeJohnson I could see it either way to be honest. I personally lean towards the side that likes an explanation. In this case it could have been including a line why they should be using equals method instead of the `!=` to compare methods. It gives the questioner an answer for their current issue, while at the same time teaches them why it is an answer. Just as a note, I came across your answer through the review system for low quality posts. Which also explains why I left the comment on yours and not the other 90% of the answers here that are pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .equals method instead.

```
String cont = "";
do {
// Loop stuff

System.out.print("another item (y/n)?");
cont = input.next();
} while ( !"n".equals(cont) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( !"n".equalsIgnoreCase(cont) )
```